# Connecting to Active Directory via node.js

Tags: c#, node.js, active-directory

Is there a way to connect to Active Directory using binding to Active Directory Domain Services the same that the C# class [DirectoryEntry(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87tye19w(v=vs.100).aspx) creator does but from a Node.js server? I'm trying to connect to AD using the [node-activedirectory](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory) package, but I can't manage to do it without credentials (which a C# app set up in the same domain does without any problems using the mentioned above class creator). Or maybe I got confused at some point, but it's still possible? I would be very grateful for any insight - thanks in advance.

Best regards

Piotr

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this Piotr? I'm trying to achieve something similar.